Unexpected Li-Ion ESR
I used a Keithley 2281S-20-6 battery simulator to characterize and generate a model of a Samsung INR18650-30Q Li-Ion battery.  I was surprised to see that the ESR increased with SOC rather than decreased.  Is this normal behavior or should I be suspicious of this test equipment?


I'm not very familiar with Keithley tools but do they happen to have any sort of thermal compensation?

@Colin - Good question - not that I can gather from the documentation.  There is no sensor on the battery anyway.  It was not very warm to the touch during testing though, so I'd be surprised if that were the issue.

Try testing it on a different battery

Is it a raw cell or does it have protection added?

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany - it's a bare cell; no protection

@VoltageSpike - I'm rerunning the characterization after after purging the data buffers on the instrument. I'm wondering if I had mixed data in it.  If that doesn't give better results, I'll try another cell.  Unfortunately it takes a whole day to run the characterization.

It looks like something indeed went wrong with the Keithley 2281S-20-6, though I'm not sure what.  I cleared the data buffers on the instrument and retested with the same battery and got much better results.  My best guess is that data buffers contained stale data from previous tests, though no mention of clearing the buffer is made in reference manual when describing how to perform ESR measurements.

